# POST datas via Angular.post and retrieve it as JSON through servlet

Tags: java, json, angular, post, servlets

I have an interface as so:

```
export interface Product {
    product: string;
    quantity: number;
    status: string;
}
```

I post an Array populated with datas of this interface type:

```
  sendDatas(productsArray:Product[])
  {
    const header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json'});
    const options = {headers : header};
    this.http.post<any>("/ssservice", JSON.stringify(productsArray), options).subscribe();
  }
```

I want to retrieve the data sended with Angular in my servlet as JSON (I though using GSON library) and eventually know if that's not too much how to
to finally convert it to a `List<List<Object>>`type

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
   WhichTypeToUse? JSONvalue = request.iDontKnowWhatMethodToUseToGrabValues();
   List<List<Object>> convertedValues = HowCanIconvertTheValues(JSONvalue)
}
```

How can I achieve that? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so your questions are a) how to get `POSTED` data in a servlet b) How to parse JSON and convert to Object

Comment: @ScaryWombat Exactly. Convert it to Object is kind of the finality I can delete it of the post if you think this is too much for one post.The object part it not crucial

Comment: I suggest that you try searching using the hints I have given you.

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry let me correct I know how to get posted data in a servlet but not this type. I know how a to get a simple json with two parameters and retrieve data calling `request.getParameter("parameterName")`. But that obviously won't be the good solution for an array of json values based on the same interface. I've tried doing some research without any satisfying solutions. So that's the first thing. Now for the object conversion I'll check after I've Found the first soultion. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *But that obviously won't be the good solution for an array of json values* - maybe I don't how, but my guess is that this would just come across as a normal parameter - how you tried? It maybe encoded when you get it though.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'll try what I understand of your suggestion and get back to you. Many thanks